# Add Go Test binary to container_image using Bazel

Tags: docker, go, integration-testing, bazel, bazel-rules

I am building a go test package that I would like to have included in a Docker image.  The binary can be built using `bazel build //testing/e2e:e2e_test`.  This creates a binary in the bazel_bin folder.  Now I would like to take this binary and add it to a docker image...

```
container_image(
    name = "image",
    base = "@alpine_linux_amd64//image",
    entrypoint = ["/e2e_test"],
    files = [":e2e_test"],
)
```

This gives me the following error

```
ERROR: ...BUILD.bazel:27:16: in container_image_ rule //testing/e2e:image: non-test target '//testing/e2e:image' depends on testonly target '//testing/e2e:e2e_test' and doesn't have testonly attribute set
ERROR: Analysis of target '//testing/e2e:image' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//testing/e2e:image' failed
```

Ultimately, what I am trying to accomplish is creating a application that contains a suite of end to end tests using the Go Test framework.  I can then distribute these tests in a docker container to be run in testing environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that a non-testonly target depends on a testonly one, which [the docs for testonly](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#common.testonly) say isn't allowed:

> If True, only testonly targets (such as tests) can depend on this target.
>
> Equivalently, a rule that is not `testonly` is not allowed to depend on any rule that is `testonly`.

You can do what you're looking for by making your target `testonly` like this:

```py
container_image(
    name = "image",
    testonly = True,
    base = "@alpine_linux_amd64//image",
    entrypoint = ["/e2e_test"],
    files = [":e2e_test"],
)
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you very much Brian